# how to count using proc sql certain conditions

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset (patients) as such:

```
Pat_ID     Hos     Date

A              11        1/1/2012

B              12         2/3/2012

B              13         2/3/2012

C              11         4/1/2012

C               11         4/5/2012
```

How do I count using proc sql such that the outcome looks something like this:

```
Pat_ID      Visits

A                 1

B                 1

C                 2
```

Since B has two visits on the same date, they are considered as only 1 visit, whereas C has 2 visits because they are on different dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Pat_ID, count(distinct VisitDate) as Visits
from patient
group by Pat_ID
order by Pat_ID asc
```

Comment: An answer containing only code is not a high quality answer; please explain the method by which you solve the problem (what concepts or methods are useful to understand in solving the problem).  Teach a man to fish, don't just give him fish.